# Cannot change display of a Bootstrap multi select

Tags: javascript, html, select, bootstrap-4

I created a multi select using Bootstrap style. Everything looks very well except when I attempt to hide it by changing **style="display:none**, which does not hide it. Can you tell me why? Is there a way to solve this?

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary" multiple data-max-options="2" style="display:none">
    <option>PHP</option>
    <option>JAVASCRIPT</option>
    <option>HTML</option>

  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a wrapper div around your select tag like this

```
<div style="display:none">
    <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary" multiple data-max-options="2" style="display:none">
      <option>PHP</option>
      <option>JAVASCRIPT</option>
      <option>HTML</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add !important to the style it will override the current style.

> display:none !important

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary" multiple data-max-options="2" style="display:none !important;">
    <option>PHP</option>
    <option>JAVASCRIPT</option>
    <option>HTML</option>

  </select>
```